# Why does '\n' else known as 'linebreak' returns a weird symbol when trying to write "$value \n" in a .txt file using PHP?

Tags: php

I have a php script, in which I read an `$array` and `fwrite` the desired value to a `.txt` file.

**PHP Code**:

```
<?php
$array = unserialize(file_get_contents('rawdata.txt'));

$handle = fopen("ean.txt", "a");

foreach ( $array as $key=>$value ) {
    if ( $key != 0 ) {
        echo $value[21]."<br>";
    }
    fwrite($handle, "$value[21]\n");
}
?>
```

**Note**: when I `print_r()` the `$array` all values from the `.txt` file are displayed correctly.
But when I try to `fwrite()` the array in another `.txt` file I get this Symbol on the position that I should get the `\n`.

Symbol: ਠ

**Questions**: Why is this happening? What should I look for to try and troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks in advance for your time and effort!

Comment: You have an error in your script, in here: `fwrite($handle, "$value[21]\n");`

Comment: The [documentation gives you the answer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) - see "**note**". Have you tried `\r\n`? I also think you could refactor and simply using `file_put_contents` would be better suited here, with the `FILE_APPEND` flag.

Comment: Try to use universal End-of-line symbol `PHP_EOL`. Like this `fwrite($handle, $value[21].PHP_EOL)`;

Comment: I don't see anything wrong at first sight. It's either an encoding problem, or `$value[21]` doesn't have what you think it does. Please run `var_dump($value[21], bin2hex($value[21])` and add its output to the question.

Comment: I tried all the variations and codes you guys left here for me, and unfortunately they didn't change anything related to what the results are. But because I dont want to bother you without me having completely understood the `problem` I will leave this question active, and make a more advance research before editting it again. Thank you all for yout time and efforts.

Comment: [var_dump()](https://php.net/var_dump) and [bin2hex()](https://php.net/bin2hex) ( follow the links for details) are tools to obtain the information needed to diagnose the issue, which is the step before finding a fix. They aren't expected to change or solve anything by themselves.